# MySQL-python is not getting installed in virtualenv(EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found)

Tags: python, mysql, django, virtualenv, mysql-python

I am building a django project that needs mysql as backend.

I have created a virtualenv and try to install MySQL-python using pip

```
pip install MySQL-python
    Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python==1.2.5
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB): 108kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/home/sayone/virtual/myvinotype/build/MySQL-python/setup.py) egg_info for package MySQL-python
    sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
........
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

By searching I have found that I need to install libmysqlclient-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but 10.0.21+maria-1~trusty is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

To install `MySQL-python` we need to install  `libmysqlclient-dev` but it end up in unmet dependency with mariadb(not sure)

Os:Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit:** After installing `sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev` I am able to install `MySQL-python` without any problem(I am not sure this can be added as answer).

Comment: If you are using python version 3.4, I would recommend you to switch back to version 2.7. There are issues in version 3.4 when installing mysql.

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) recommend to use `mysqlclient` instead of `MySQL-python`. It works with Python 3.3+, so there is no need to downgrade to 2.7.

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Run `apt-cache policy libmysqlclient18` & you'll see that you have a version of `libmysqlclient18` from `mariadb`. If they don't provide a dev package then you'll need to live without the dev package or get rid of mariadb & whatever it's installed

Comment: apt-cache policy libmysqlclient18
libmysqlclient18:
  Installed: 10.0.21+maria-1~trusty
  Candidate: 10.0.21+maria-1~trusty
  Version table:
 *** 10.0.21+maria-1~trusty 0
        500 http://ams2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64

Comment: Ajay Gupta I did not get exactly what I should do, please find the result of `apt-cache policy libmysqlclient18` on above comment. But after `sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev` I can install  `MySQL-python` without any trouble.